# What is the difference between a moving average and a regression of a time dependent variable?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

Suppose that you have a time dependent data generating process which you are trying to model using either a moving average model or a (linear) regression. I have a couple of questions for these models:

1. Are both of these two approaches appropriate to reflect changes in the data over time? That is, are they appropriate to model the time dependency of the data generating process like for example changes in the mean or variance of the process?
2. Can we say that the moving average model uses a local window to describe the data and that the regression model uses a global window?
3. Are there any simple rules/ criteria to help me decide when should I use a moving average model and when a regression?

Comment: Flagging to close as "Needs More Focus". The point here isn't to have a long winded debate about the methods - and their hundreds of possible applications. It's straightforward to write down the model's expressions and see their specific applications.

Comment: Consider that in all these 3 years and the rampant production of COVID incidence and death curves, almost all methods used a filtering process. By definition, a filter cannot predict "waves" and yet every news caster and airmchair epidemiologist felt confident doing so based on "upturns".

Answer (score 0):

At every time instant, moving average uses few past samples to calculate the moving average. It is a statistic to smooth out random short-term fluctuations in a data series. So, you use same variable past data to calculate same variable current data.

Regression on the other hand uses values of lot of other variables to predict the value of another variable. Variables used as input are called as independent variables, where as the output variable is called as dependent variable. There is no concept of time instant at all here.

Examples:
Moving Average: Stock Analysis, Temperature Analysis, Rainfall Analysis (all time data)
Regression: House Price Prediction, Cancer Prediction (no time data)

Comment: There are many applications of regression to time series data.  One simple one would be to fit a trend. There are many others. So, "not at all" is quite wrong.

Comment: Thanks @NickCox . I have modified my answer.

Comment: Moving average = moving intercepts in a regression model.  Better to use moving intercepts **and** slopes, i.e., use the _loess_ nonparametric smoother.